# Can I edit theme CSS without FTP access to the files?

Tags: 7, theming

Can I edit Drupal theme CSS files with out the ability to download/upload css files using FTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without server access of some description either via FTP or SSH (for example) - you can't edit the files.

You could, however, try [CSS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) if you are able to install modules through the UI.

> Allows administrators to inject CSS into the page output based on
>   configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple CSS tweaks without
>   modifying a site's official theme -- for example, a 'nighttime' color
>   scheme could be added during certain hours. The CSS is added using
>   Drupal's standard drupal_add_css() function and respects page caching,
>   etc.